# How to create custom keyboard layouts for Windows 10 with 3-keystrokes-combination for a character?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am looking for a program which will allow me to build **custom keyboard layouts for Windows 10**, and will allow **entering a single character with 3-keystrokes-combination**.

I need to do this to create a **phonetic input method** for **Bengali language**.
I already tried Microsoft Keyboard Layout Editor, but it only allows maximum 2-keystrokes per character.

Any solution or suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Clavier+](http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php?sLang=en) can automate character entry using multi-key combinations, at least for Latin, Cyrillic and some other alphabets, but I've not tried it for Bengali. There are many [alternatives to Clavier+](http://alternativeto.net/software/clavier/), as well.

However, this is not a very good answer, I admit, because it seems you'd have to enter separate versions of each consonant for different vowel diacritics. If this is useless for your purposes, please let me know to delete this answer.